# Dynamically split columns in pandas dataframe by the same character

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

I have about a bunch columns that need to be split on a colon (:). Is there a way I can do that without having to specify every single split. Sometimes the record has 2 colons and sometimes 3.

Example data:

```
        DATE      TALK_TIME   CONSULT_TIME
0     2023-11-21       NaN        05:10 
1     2023-11-21  00:04:16          NaN
2     2023-11-21       NaN          NaN
3     2023-11-21  00:24:30          NaN
4     2023-11-21  00:04:08          NaN
```

my code:

```
# doing this for every column that needs to be split.. very meticulous

df[['TALK_TIME1', 'TALK_TIME2', 'TALK_TIME3']] = df['TALK_TIME'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df[['CONSULT_TIME1', 'CONSULT_TIME2']] = df['CONSULT_TIME'].str.split(':', expand=True)
```

Output I want

```
      DATE         TALK_TIME1   TALK_TIME2  TALK_TIME3  CONSULT_TIME1  CONSULT_TIME2
0     2023-11-21        NaN       NaN        NaN            05             10
1     2023-11-21        00         04         16           NaN             NaN
2     2023-11-21        NaN       NaN        NaN           NaN             NaN
3     2023-11-21        00         24         30           NaN             NaN
4     2023-11-21        00         04         08           NaN             NaN
```

Comment: FWIW, if these represent timespans, have you considered converting them into [`TimeDelta`](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)s instead?

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of the columns to split, than loop over them to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), finally [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all those output together with the non-target columns:

```
cols = ['TALK_TIME', 'CONSULT_TIME']

# process the target columns
lst = [df[col].str.split(':', expand=True)
       .rename(columns=lambda x: f'{col}_{x+1}')
       for col in cols
      ]

# concatenate
out = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=cols)]+lst, axis=1)

# cleanup
del lst
```

Output:

```
         DATE TALK_TIME_1 TALK_TIME_2 TALK_TIME_3 CONSULT_TIME_1 CONSULT_TIME_2
0  2023-11-21         NaN         NaN         NaN             05             10
1  2023-11-21          00          04          16            NaN            NaN
2  2023-11-21         NaN         NaN         NaN            NaN            NaN
3  2023-11-21          00          24          30            NaN            NaN
4  2023-11-21          00          04          08            NaN            NaN
```